# Why the view is unable to show students data on client side and it is ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Firstly these are the model classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public string RollNo;
    public string Branch;
    public string Course;
    public string Year;
}

public class StudentData
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> Data()
    {
        List<Student> StudentsList = new List<Student>();

        Student[] SArr = new Student[4];
        SArr[0].ID = 1;
        SArr[0].Name = "Narender";
        SArr[0].RollNo = "0177EC161067";
        SArr[0].Branch = "EC";
        SArr[0].Course = "B.E";
        SArr[0].Year = "IV";

        StudentsList.Add(SArr[0]);

        SArr[1].ID = 2;
        SArr[1].Name = "Sandeep";
        SArr[1].RollNo = "0177CS161001";
        SArr[1].Branch = "CSE";
        SArr[1].Course = "B.E";
        SArr[1].Year = "IV";

        StudentsList.Add(SArr[1]);
        return StudentsList;
    }
}
```

And this is the controller:

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        StudentData students = new StudentData();
        IEnumerable<Student> s = students.Data();

        return View(s.ToList());
    }
}
```

The view is this:

```
@model IEnumerable<FirstApp.Models.Student>
<table width="400">
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Roll Number</th>
<th>Branch</th>
<th>Course</th>
<th>Year</th>
@foreach (var s in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@s.ID</td>
            <td>@s.Name</td>
            <td>@s.RollNo</td>
            <td>@s.Branch</td>
            <td>@s.Course</td>
            <td>@s.Year</td>
        </tr>``
    }
</table>
```

I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 26:             SArr[0].ID = 1;

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" always has the same cause: you tried to dereference an object variable that is set to null.  Do what it suggests: *review your stack trace.*

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where you return the view, and examine the values you are passing in s.

Comment: Why are you using an array *and* a list here?

Comment: I have done it but unable to understand the reason behind the "System.NullReferenceException". What changes do you suggest in code?

Comment: I am using an array and a list here because before that I was just initializing a student object and adding them one by one at that time only last student details were showing the number of time foreach block was executing.

Comment: `Student[] SArr = new Student[4];` - this will only create a **container** to hold 4 students - but the individual `Student` objects in the array are **NOT** initialized yet! You need to do `SArr[0] = new Student();` for each of the four "spots" **before** you access any of their properties!

Comment: Ohh now I understood the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated view

```
@using FirstApp.Models
@model IEnumerable<Student>
<table width="400">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Roll Number</th>
        <th>Branch</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var s in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@s.ID</td>
            <td>@s.Name</td>
            <td>@s.RollNo</td>
            <td>@s.Branch</td>
            <td>@s.Course</td>
            <td>@s.Year</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Updated models will be:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
        public string RollNo;
        public string Branch;
        public string Course;
        public string Year;
    }

    public class StudentData
    {
        public IEnumerable<Student> Data()
        {
            return new List<Student>{
                new Student{
                ID = 1,
                Name = "Narender",
                RollNo = "0177EC161067",
                Branch = "EC",
                Course = "B.E",
                Year = "IV"
                },
                new Student{
                    ID = 2,Name = "Sandeep",
                    RollNo = "0177CS161001",
                    Branch = "CSE",
                    Course = "B.E",
                    Year = "IV"
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give me an idea, from where I can learn these things? Actually, I am a beginner in C#.NET and ASP.NET. I was just trying to implement whatever I have learnt.

Comment: check Microsoft Docs, it is one of the most complete documentation sites I know. For cases like this, maybe you could start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: You can find all these details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp If this solution works, please mark this as an answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an Array and a List.

Update your model class as such:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace FirstApp.Models
{
public class Student
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public string RollNo;
    public string Branch;
    public string Course;
    public string Year;
}
public class StudentData
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> Data()
    {
        var StudentsList = new List<Student>()
        {
           new Student(){
            ID = 1,
            Name = "Narender",
            RollNo = "0177EC161067",
            Branch = "EC",
            Course = "B.E",
            Year = "IV"
           },
           new Student(){
            ID = 2,
            Name = "Sandeep",
            RollNo = "0177CS161001",
            Branch = "CSE",
            Course = "B.E",
            Year = "IV"
           }
        };
        return StudentsList;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Okay and Thanks a lot.